# How to group as defined by having their first element common, and keep them in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list as

```
list1 = [(4356, 'OPIL', 2), (4356, 'OILY', 3), (5986, 'UISL', 1), (6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]
```

I want output to be like this:
Output:

```
result = [[(4356, 'OPIL', 2),(4356, 'OILY', 3)],[(5986, 'UISL', 1)], [(6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]]
```

How do we do it?

Comment: What do you want to happen for items that share a first element, but are not adjacent?  Should `[(1, 2), ('a', 'b'), (1, 3)]` be `[[(1, 2), (1, 3)], [('a', 'b')]]` or remain unchanged?

Comment: I already covered this in the question itself if you look into it @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [(4356, 'OPIL', 2), (4356, 'OILY', 3), (5986, 'UISL', 1), (6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]

l = [list(v) for g, v in groupby(list1, key=lambda v: v[0])]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[(4356, 'OPIL', 2), (4356, 'OILY', 3)], [(5986, 'UISL', 1)], [(6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *items inside the list are sorted*, you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [1]: list1 = [(4356, 'OPIL', 2), (4356, 'OILY', 3), (5986, 'UISL', 1), (6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]

In [2]: from itertools import groupby

In [3]: from operator import itemgetter

In [4]: [list(g) for _, g in groupby(list1, key=itemgetter(0))]
Out[4]: 
[[(4356, 'OPIL', 2), (4356, 'OILY', 3)],
 [(5986, 'UISL', 1)],
 [(6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]]
```

---

If there are not sorted, you can either pre-sort the list before using `groupby()`, or use a different strategy - for instance, using [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group "similar" items:

```
In [5]: from collections import defaultdict

In [6]: grouped = defaultdict(list)

In [7]: for item in list1:
            grouped[item[0]].append(item)   

In [8]: [grouped[key] for key in sorted(grouped)] 
Out[8]: 
[[(4356, 'OPIL', 2), (4356, 'OILY', 3)],
 [(5986, 'UISL', 1)],
 [(6985, 'LIBK', 3), (6985, 'LIBK', 1)]]
```